# Is it appropriate to delete a link-only answer in review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, answers, link-only-answers

Supposing the question was already answered and accepted, this would be an obvious yes. *Delete*

Supposing this was the only answer, and the OP posted a thank you comment or otherwise marked it correct, I would certainly not want to delete it as it would not have a chance to be edited/improved. *Skip* or *Looks OK*? (I don't want to take the time to *Edit*, but obviously that is the preferred choice)

Supposing this was the only answer, and there were no clues to whether it was helpful, is it really appropriate to delete?

Comment: Presumably, when it's appropriate to flag it NaA, it's appropriate to go the whole way... Anyway, rest assured you won't be asked to delete an accepted answer unless you become a mod: Only they can do so.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking all the wrong questions. You only need the answer to one:

### Does this answer, clearly and cleanly, *attempt to answer the question?*

- Linking to something else isn't an answer, unless the question was "can I get a link to something?".
- Conversely, linking to more information on a terse answer *doesn't make that any less of an answer.*
- Unintelligible squawkings might have been intended to answer, but if no one can tell then they might as well not have been.
- Requests for clarification, follow-up questions, "thanks!" / "I too have this problem, halp?"... are not attempts to answer.

...you get the idea.

#### See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)