# Got review banned for one failed audit; I acted on the post but not in the way that it would expect

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

The audit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6438099

I probably should have skipped it instead of selecting no action needed, but I preformed an action on the question itself (Flagged for closure).  The question is looking for software, and the answer received provides software.  Following the advice seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266098/3991344), this answer ***does***, clearly and cleanly, attempt to answer the question.

The issue is that the message being given that I am review-banned only links to this one audit.

> [image: You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6438099. Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.]

I don't know which other ones I have failed, as the last time I remember it happening was about a month ago.

- What other audits did I fail that triggered this?  Don't the hundreds of successful reviews and audit passes counteract those?
- What proper action should I have taken here?  (Audit-wise, I know I should have downvoted/ect, but was my actual action of flaging to close the question and then selecting "No action needed" the proper one?)

Comment: moderators can ban reviewers individually as well

Comment: The fact that you took action on the question is fine by itself but that doesn't invalidate the review.

Comment: Before I decided to get rid of audits by just not reviewing one of my conclusions was that the audit system requires a very narrow view of each review item. Think outside the box and you will fail audits.

Answer (score 15):

You can't get banned for just one failed audit. It takes multiple. The "window" for how long the failed audit counts against you, at least in terms of possibly leading to a ban, is one month. In other words, if you fail an audit today, if you fail an audit in the next 30 days, you'll get a temporary ban.

The bans increment, the lowest being 2 days, then if you fail again within 30 days, 7 days, then, if failed again within 3 weeks, a 1 month ban.

After the full month ban, this resets, as you haven't completed any reviews in the last 30 days and so couldn't fail another one within a month, and you'd start with a two day ban again if you fail 2 audits. You can read more about this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/4015623). "The duration for automatic review bans takes into account how often you have been banned in the past 30 days"

Your previous failure of an audit must have been within the last 30 days!

The successful reviews and correct audit actions don't counteract these in any way. The rule holders reviewers to high standards.

As for proper action, if you're not sure, **skip it**. That's the safest route. If you have any doubt, let someone else deal with it.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely accurate, specifically the part about the 30-day window.  Unless you have a source, the 30-day window only appears to address how long you get banned, not whether you get banned to begin with.  What exactly triggers the ban has not been made public to the best of my knowledge

Comment: @psubsee2003 let me see the source. I read this on Shog's post - I'll go find it.

Comment: @rene I don't see a 3 week ban either - if you fail another audit within 3 weeks of a 1 week ban, you get a one month ban

Comment: Lack of coffee must have confused me...

Comment: @psubsee2003 see this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/4015623 "The duration for automatic review bans takes into account how often you have been banned in the past 30 days"

Comment: @AlexK that is absolutely correct, but no where does it say that you have to fail 2 audits in a 30-day period to trigger a ban in the first place.  The 30-day window only deals with duration not the initial ban.  Your 1st and 4th paragraph are incorrect to the best of my knowledge, as is part of your 3rd paragraph.