# What is wrong in this review?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

As I was reviewing post I got first answer in the image as Review first post. As I found it ok so I clicked no need to Review and after that I got one message "Review Audit failed (Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing)".

But when I checked the real post (you can see in the second answer in the image, its accepted which means it is helpful) it is same as the answer I reviewed. So what is the problem in my review?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I suspect it was a direct copy of the original answer and the copy was deleted.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I am also thinking the same, but from my side i found that links are related to the question asked. But now I cannot any review tasks for next 7 days.

Comment: Well that means you would have failed other review audits, you should check your history to make sure you are reviewing propely.

Comment: related: [Is it appropriate to delete a link-only answer in review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266089/is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-link-only-answer-in-review-queue)

Comment: I would mark this answer as not an answer. It might have helped but it is of no use for SO. I've learnt that the solution should be included in the answer and not the pure links only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That user did indeed post an exact copy of the accepted answer as a new answer.

But past that, even if there *wasn't* a copy of that answer, **it should still be deleted**, and your failure of that audit was correct. All they have provided is two links to external sites. That is **not an answer** and you should have recommended its deletion. There is nothing "ok" about that answer.